# Is there any closed form solution for the following integral?

Tags: integration

I was wondering if any closed form solution exists for the following integral? I know the integral is convergent and it can be solved numerically. However, I want to know if it can be expressed based on known functions (gamma, Bessel, etc.)? Any help would be appreciated.

$$\int_{x=0}^\infty {(ax+b)}^{-1-c}{e}^{{-(ax+b)}^{-c}}{\left(\frac{d}{x}+h\right)}^{-1-f}{e}^{{-\left(\frac{d}{x}+h\right)}^{-f}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

$a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $h$, and $f$ are real numbers.

In my research I have a random variable $t$ following a generalized extreme value (GEV) distribution. The mean of this random variable $T$ also follows a GEV distribution. I'm looking for a compound GEV distribution which accounts for the variability of both random variables. After compounding the two distributions, the raw form of the distribution is as follow:

$$f(t)=\frac{ad}{(\xi_t)(\xi_T)(t)}\int_{x=0}^\infty {(ax+b)}^{-1-1/\xi_t}{e}^{{-(ax+b)}^{-1/\xi_t}}{(d/x+h)}^{-1-1/\xi_T}{e}^{{-(d/x+h)}^{-1/\xi_T}}dx$$

where:

$$a=\frac{\Gamma(1-\xi_T)-1}{\widetilde T(1-\mu_T)}$$
$$b=1-\frac{\mu_T[\Gamma(1-\xi_T)-1]}{1-\mu_T}$$
$$d=\frac{t[\Gamma(1-\xi_t)-1]}{1-\mu_t}$$
$$e=1-\frac{\mu_t[\Gamma(1-\xi_t)-1]}{1-\mu_t}$$
In the above equations $\widetilde T$ , $\mu_T$ and $\mu_t$ are positive real numbers which are higher than 1. $t$ is a real number. $\xi_T$ and $\xi_t$ are also real numbers but in the range of $[−0.5,0.5]$.
I should also add that the chance of the above parameters become integers are very low, so it would be reasonable to assume that they can't be integers.

I should also add that the chance of the above parameters become integers are very low, so it would be reasonable to assume that they can't be integers.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to do integration by part, breaking the whole into the following two functions: 
$${(ax+b)}^{-1-c}{e}^{{-(ax+b)}^{-c}}$$
and
$${(d/x+h)}^{-1-f}{e}^{{-(d/x+h)}^{-f}}$$
The integration of the first part is fairly easy, but things get even more complicated to integrate the multiplication of the integral of the first part and the derivative of the second part.

Comment: This integral is  actually part of a complex probability distribution function that I obtained based on mixing two generalized extreme value distributions, so it is convergent. I have also tested the distribution for different values of a and c in MATLAB and it was convergent.

Comment: @user21820: Done!

Comment: @Xander Henderson: I edited the original post to address your previous comment. Thanks!

Comment: @Monas: Thank you! I'll remove my now redundant comment. =)